# GAS - Splitting a string on a new line from a string adds a comma

Tags: arrays, string, google-apps-script, split

I'm trying to create a comparison between the two strings after removing the new line input. However, the comparison still fails due to a comma (,) being added to the string when the split method is used on the string.  Unable to figure out why this is the case. Thanks for any help

```js
      var test_Array = ['Chess', 'Chess\n'];
      
      if (test_Array[0] == test_Array[1].split('\n'))
      {
        console.log('Test');
      }

      console.log(test_Array[0] + ' - ' + test_Array[1].split('\n'));
```

Comment: To avoid getting downvoted, please explain what's wrong with the question so that I can avoid this in future questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) returns a array. You need to  access it's first element `[0]`

```js
  var test_Array = ['Chess', 'Chess\n'];
  
  if (test_Array[0] == test_Array[1].split('\n')[0])
  {
console.log('Test');
  }

  console.log(test_Array[0] + ' - ' + test_Array[1].split('\n')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
function myfunk() {
  var test_Array = ['Chess', 'Chess\n'];
  if (test_Array[0] == (test_Array[1].split('\n')[0])) {
    Logger.log('Test');
  }
  
  Logger.log(test_Array[0] + ' - ' + test_Array[1].split('\n')[0])
}
```

The comma was just the default delimiter for split

```
Execution log
9:55:06 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:55:07 AM  Info    Test
9:55:07 AM  Info    Chess - Chess
9:55:08 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Staring at the problem didn't help. Thanks for the assistance on this.